# Looking for an idea how to measure line count

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, line, css

I want to take a text on a webpage and measure it's height in lines, regardless of any other parameter,
so if I shrink the text width and get more lines, i will get the new line count.

Any ideas how to do that using JS and jQuery?

Also, what kind of line numbering techniques are common?

Comment: Height of your text wrapper divided by the height of `<div style=height:1em></div>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost same idea as Ghommey's comment, but with line-height instead of height.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/vbCJm/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small jQuery function doing it:

```
$.fn.numLines = function() {
    var tmp = $('<div style="visibility:hidden;">x</div>').appendTo(document.body);
    var lines = this.height() / tmp.height();
    tmp.remove();
    return lines;
};
```

You simply call `$('#someElement').numLines()` to retrieve the number of lines.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/sHzMP/

Comment: thanx, but I don't completely understand, why do you use the invisible div instead just line-height?

Comment: Didn't think about line-height.

Answer (score 0):

This will give total number of line in given text

```
  text.split("\n").length
```